# What's the benefits of conforming to a protocol and do I need to declare it so if a superclass does?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm writing a quick simple table view app. I've declared the view I'm creating the table view in to be a subclass of UITableViewController. UITableViewController conforms to the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols.

My question is, does my view which is the subclass of UITableViewController, also need to state it conforms to these protocols?

Also what is the advantage on conforming to a protocol, meaning putting  after the subclass? The code I write works provided the methods are there regardless of the protocol being mentioned in the header.

Does it make a difference if I added a UITableView into a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: To answer your last question: no.  You can subclass UITableViewController, **or** you can subclass UIViewController and add a UITableView outlet.  If you implement the delegate or data source protocols for table view, you should declare them in the interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you inherit from a class that conforms to those protocols, no, you do not need to state that you conform to them in your subclass.

The advantage to stating that you conform to your protocol is that some delegate properties will require an instance of a class that explicitly states it conforms to them.  Also, it's just a good idea to state that you conform to a protocol if you, in fact, do.

Comment: So it's as much a matter of good programming practice in those cases where it's not essential to have done so?

Comment: conforming to a protocol is essentially saying "I implement this group of methods".  Implementing the protocol's methods without explicitly stating you conform to it in the header is akin to calling a method on an object that you implement, but do not declare in the header.  So, I guess you could say it's good practice.